# Error when trying to consent Azure VPN application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-vpn

I am trying to setup a p2s VPN using Azure Active Directory authentication. I am following the steps described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/openvpn-azure-ad-tenant. In the section Authorize the application, it's mentioned that we need to grant admin consent, so that Azure VPN application can sign in and read user profiles. I am logged in as GlobalAdmin, but when I paste the required URL (https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=41b23e61-6c1e-4545-b367-cd054e0ed4b4&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://portal.azure.com&nonce=1234&prompt=admin_consent) I am redirected to the portal with url:

[https://portal.azure.com/?error=access_denied&error_description=AADSTS650054:+The+application+'api://41b23e61-6c1e-4545-b367-cd054e0ed4b4/api'+asked+for+permissions+to+access+a+resource+that+has+been+removed+or+is+no+longer+available.+Contact+the+app+vendor](https://portal.azure.com/?error=access_denied&error_description=AADSTS650054:+The+application+%27api://41b23e61-6c1e-4545-b367-cd054e0ed4b4/api%27+asked+for+permissions+to+access+a+resource+that+has+been+removed+or+is+no+longer+available.+Contact+the+app+vendor).

What am I doing incorrectly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above behavior was a code bug which was fixed by the Azure VPN and Azure AD Product Groups team and below is the RCA (Root Cause Analysis) for same:

**Issue:** When setting up a P2S VPN using Azure Active Directory authentication following the steps described in our public doc tutorial and trying to grant admin consent to the Azure VPN application using GlobalAdmin account, the public URL redirects to "https://portal.azure.com/?error=access_denied&error_description=AADSTS650054:+The+application+'api://41b23e61-6c1e-4545-b367-cd054e0ed4b4/api'+asked+for+permissions+to+access+a+resource+that+has+been+removed+or+is+no+longer+available.+Contact+the+app+vendor" and doesn't give the prompt to accept the requested permissions.

**Root Cause:**
Admin Consent was failing for new customers as Azure VPN was trying to get access to Azure AD Graph and this is deprecated.
Refer : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/migrate-azure-ad-graph-configure-permissions?tabs=http%2Cupdatepermissions-azureadgraph-powershell
This impacted only new Tenants who want to onboard to VPN and not existing customers. Some code was updated in the backend which broke the admin consent flow. The app access has been changed to Microsoft Graph now and the newly added code was removed from the Azure VPN client app from the backend which has fixed the issue.

**Solution:**
Now if you follow the documentation/guide [Configure Azure AD tenant and settings for P2S VPN connections: Azure AD authentication: OpenVPN - Azure VPN Gateway | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/openvpn-azure-ad-tenant#authorize-the-application), the public URL at Step 2 should work without any issues.

Comment: The note from that documentation is important if you're using just-in-time access: "_If you're using a global admin account that is not native to the Microsoft Entra tenant to provide consent, replace "common" with the Microsoft Entra tenant ID in the URL._"